# How to login user without redirecting cakephp 3?

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I have an application where the user is added using ajax. I want to log them in, but not redirect them so that the other form(s) can be submitted. Is this possible? I have searched the documentation, but couldn't see anything to make it not redirect. I saw you can change the redirect, but how do you not make it redirect at all? I keep getting an err_too_many_redirects, even when I try to redirect to the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config Auth component as bellow:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => false
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you... it works. I added the loginRedirect and logoutRedirect false to my app controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using Nguyễn Anh Tuấn's answer, but just in case someone else comes across this problem as well, it might be worth adding how to do this inside a sub controller, and not just the AppController like I did.

(Just to point out, you can load the Auth component and set the configurations in a different controller like shown [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#configuring-components), but you can also just set the configuration options instead.)

When adding 'loginRedirect' => false to the AppController and a user tries to access pages they aren't authorized for, I get the warning "Warning (2): Illegal string offset '_base' [CORE\src\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php, line 408].

If the redirects are set in the AppController, then nothing happens when a user tried to access those pages (it stays on the current page).

So, I looked up in the docs and found [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#configuring-components).

I just added the line

```
$this->Auth->config('loginRedirect', false);
```

to my Users Controller in the initialize method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Battousai:

You can do this way as well: `$this->Auth->config('loginRedirect', false)`

Base on the way you want to do.